# Google drive file upload using Service account of

Tags: php, file-upload, google-drive-api

I want to save the file to Google Drive from the php site. For this, I'm using the Api Key (in JSON form) of Service Accounts in the Google developer console Apis & Services and I am using it for free with any purchase to upload files in in Drive folder.
Now the problem is that It takes 8 to 9 seconds to upload files to drive, no matter how fast your internet connection is. I want to optimize it so that It will completely depend on the network speed.  In the PHP site, I am using  (composer require Google/apiclient:^2.15).

```
(Upload File)
function uploadFiles($file, $folderName, $fileName, $driveId )
{
try {
    set_time_limit(60);
    $client = new Google_Client();
    putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=./api_key.json');
    $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
    $client->addScope(Drive::DRIVE);
    $driveService = new Drive($client);
    $existingFolder = getFolderByName($driveService, $folderName, $driveId);
    if ($existingFolder) {
        $existingFile = getFileByName($driveService, $fileName, $existingFolder->id);
        if ($existingFile) {
            if (deleteFile($driveService, $existingFile->id)) {
                return uploadFile($driveService, $file, $fileName, $existingFolder->id);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return uploadFile($driveService, $file, $fileName, $existingFolder->id);
        }
    } else {
        $createdFolder = createFolder($driveService, $folderName, $driveId);
        if ($createdFolder) {
            return uploadFile($driveService, $file, $fileName, $createdFolder);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    return 100;
  }
}
(Get Folder Name)
function getFolderByName($driveService, $folderName, $parentFolderId = null)
{
    $query = "name = '$folderName'";
    if ($parentFolderId) {
    $query .= " and '$parentFolderId' in parents";
    }
    $response = $driveService->files->listFiles([
        'q' => $query,
        'fields' => 'files(id)'
    ]);
    if (count($response->files) > 0) {
        return $response->files[0];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

(Get File Name)
function getFileByName($driveService, $fileName, $folderId = null)
{
    try {
        $params = [
            'q' => "name='$fileName'",
        ];

        if ($folderId) {
            $params['q'] .= " and '$folderId' in parents";
        }

        $results = $driveService->files->listFiles($params);

        if (count($results->getFiles()) > 0) {
            return $results->getFiles()[0];
        } else {
            return null; // File not found
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return null; // Error occurred
    }
}

(Delet File If Already Exists)
function deleteFile($driveService, $fileId)
{
    try {
        $driveService->files->delete($fileId);
        return $fileId;
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo "Error deleting file: " . $ex->getMessage();
        return null;
    }
}

(Upload File to Drive)
function uploadFile($driveService, $file, $fileName, $folderId = null)
{
    $filePath = $file['tmp_name'];
    $mimeType = mime_content_type($filePath);
    $fileMetadata = new Drive\DriveFile([
        'name' => $fileName,
        'parents' => [$folderId]
    ]);
    // $fileMetadata = new Drive\DriveFile([
    //     'name' => $fileName,
    // ]);

    // if ($folderId) {
    //     $fileMetadata->setParents([$folderId]);
    // }
    $content = file_get_contents($filePath);
    $file = $driveService->files->create(
        $fileMetadata,
        array(
            'data' => $content, // Removed the square brackets
            'mimeType' => $mimeType,
            'uploadType' => 'multipart',
            'fields' => 'id'
        )
    );
    return $file->id;
}

(Create Folder If not exists)
function createFolder($driveService, $folderName, $parentFolderId = null)
{
    // Check if the folder already exists
    $existingFolder = getFolderByName($driveService, $folderName, $parentFolderId);

    if ($existingFolder) {
        return $existingFolder->id;
    }
    $folderMetadata = new Drive\DriveFile([
        'name' => $folderName,
        'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
    ]);

    if ($parentFolderId) {
        $folderMetadata->setParents([$parentFolderId]);
    }

    $folder = $driveService->files->create($folderMetadata, [
        'fields' => 'id'
    ]);

    return $folder->id;
}
```

I want to fix the Time it is taking to upload a file to drive.
I've tested it on each part one by one, It is taking 9 seconds to uploadFile($driveService, $file, $fileName, $folderId = null) only, For the first time when no folder is created on the drive it creates a folder and saves the file, from here problem starts where it takes that much time.
Adding more to it, I am uploading a maximum of two files at one time, Here I am Calling just uploadFiles($file, $folderName, $fileName, $driveId ) function from one point after calling that function and then getting response from that function it is taking almost 10 seconds, I am working on a site where I have to host it, So, I can't afford to have this much time in response if I have good Network connection.
If you have any further query then ask me surely!

Comment: If you're uploading 4 GB of data it will take some time.

Comment: No, I am uploading Images even less than  1MB each

Comment: Have you clearly tested and identified, amongst all the different tasks this code is doing, that the upload call specifically is what takes the time. Or are you really saying that this whole php script takes 9 seconds? It wasn't totally clear, and you didn't say how you'd tested it.

Comment: I've tested it on each part one by one, It is taking 9 seconds to  uploadFile($driveService, $file, $fileName, $folderId = null) only,, For the first time when no folder is created on drive its creates folder and save file , from here problem starts

Comment: So is it `$content = file_get_contents($filePath);` which takes the time, or `$file = $driveService->files->create(`? Or a combination of the two?

Comment: you get what you pay for this is a free api.

Comment: Combination of both taking this time. and I'm using this Api for free

Comment: It is clear from the comments that your question is lacking details: How many files are your uploading in the 8-9 seconds, and how big are they? Which exact function call takes the majority of the time? In the end it might just be that Google drive uploads are as slow as this, what makes you think it can be any quicker? You can find loads of complaints about the slowness of Google drive. Add this information to your question, don't write them in a comment.

Comment: `Combination of both`...how much is each part individually taking? You should always drill down as far as you can go to the identify the smallest possible surface area for the bottleneck.

Comment: Time taken to Upload file to drive must be depend on the network speed, Suppose I am uploading file of 50kb and I have 100MB network speed then I should take less than micro seconds to upload it, but In that case it is taking 10 seconds. But why?

Comment: I want to fix this problem. Anybody can help me out, I am working on it for last couple of weeks, but couldn't found any solution.

Comment: Well a) we don't know if it's _specifically_ the upload to Drive only which takes all that time, because you haven't fully drilled down into it yet (see above), b) speed of upload is not purely dependent on network speed anyway. It depends also network contention, the speed of the hardware at either end of the connection, concurrent usage of that hardware at that time, any restrictions placed on the applications involved by the administrators of that hardware, any throttling placed on the process - e.g. google might limit bandwidth for individual users, especially if they're on a free account.

Comment: Well, Let me work on it. I'll test each part and then let you guys know! Thank You all!

Comment: ok great. It's possible you can even test inside `$driveService->files->create` in case it does lots of tasks - the source code will be available in your PHP code files.